# Multiple choice with listview android

Tags: listview, button, android-activity, multiple-choice

I'm loading a listview from database. Application has a button in the listview for showing multiple choice.Based on user's choice, a button sends data of list item clicked,to next activity. How to go about it?

Comment: Have you tried using intent.putExtra() or SharedPreferences?

Comment: Didn't try, cause there are exists a lot of data. I wish to use sqlite data base.

Comment: Load the list from your database. use one of the above methods to send the data to the next activity on each list item click

Comment: But how to do it with multiple choice ?